# how to set server.name in elasticsearch 5.5?

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to begin using x-pack and specify a https cert. In order to do so, I need each elasticsearch node to have a configured hostname (a.foo.com) instead of starting with its IP address (1.2.3.4). Otherwise, SSL fails to start up with entries like:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 127.0.0.1 found
```

I know that *kibana* can be configured with a `server.name`. Elasticsearch can't. So, how do I have ES start with a configured domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `network.host`.See:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/important-settings.html#network.host

Comment: Thanks! That led me to `network.bind_host` and `network.publish_host`, which are a finer-grained way than `network.host`.